# Does there always exist an odd number of elements?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Given a nonzero integer $k$, does there always exist a positive integer $n$ such that there are exactly an odd number of elements $i\in\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ with $\frac{2^n-1}4 < 2^ik \mod{2^n-1} < \frac{3(2^n-1)}4$? Here $a\mod b\in\{0,1,...,b-1\}$.

Comment: "exactly an odd number" doesn't make any sense -- and odd number is always exactly odd.

Comment: Heuristically, you might say those numbers modulo $2^n - 1$ are "random", in which case you expect about $n/2$ numbers to satisfy the equation. Since you can try as many $n$ as you want and the "probability" of success is about $1/2$, you'd expect you can always find such an $n$. This does not provide a proof, but unless there is some special structure I'd expect the statement to be true.

Comment: (The heuristic only works if $k$ is large compared to $n$, so small $k$ may lead to exceptions.)

Comment: Interesting question (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Taking $k = 2$ seems to be an exception. For $n \geq 3$ we have the following:

- For $0 \leq i < n-3$ we have $2^i k = 2^{i+1} < 2^{n-3} < \frac{1}{4}(2^n - 1)$ and hence $2^i k$ is not in the desired range.
- For $i = n-3$ we have $2^i k = 2^{n-2} = \frac{1}{4}2^n > \frac{1}{4}(2^n - 1)$ which is just in the desired range.
- For $i = n-2$ we have $2^i k = 2^{n-1} = \frac{1}{2}2^n$ which is also in the desired range.
- For $i = n-1$ we have $2^i k = 2^n \equiv 1$ which is not in the desired range.

So for any $n \geq 3$, the number of elements $i \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$ satisfying $$\frac 14 (2^n-1) < \left(2^ik \mod{2^n-1}\right) < \frac 34 (2^n-1)$$ is exactly $2$, which is even.

For $n = 2$ we have a lower bound of $3/4 < 1$ and upper bound of $9/4 > 2$, in which case both $i = 0$ and $i = 1$ satisfy the equation. So again, the number of elements is even.

Finally, for $n = 1$ we have a lower bound of $1/4$ and upper bound of $3/4$, and no integer is in this range. So again, the number of elements satisfying the requirement is even.

Concluding, $k = 2$ seems to be a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact, I shall show that for any positive integer $n$ and integer $k$, there are an even number of elements $i \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}$ satisfying $\frac{2^n-1}{4}<2^ik \pmod{2^n-1}<\frac{3(2^n-1)}{4}$. We shall do this by considering fixed $n$ and varying $k$.

If $n=1$, then $\frac{2^n-1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3(2^n-1)}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$. There are clearly no integers between $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$, so the number of $i$ satisfying the condition is $0$, which is even.

If $n=2$, then $\frac{2^n-1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{3(2^n-1)}{4}=\frac{9}{4}$, so $\frac{3}{4}<2^ik \pmod{3}<\frac{9}{4} \Leftrightarrow 2^ik \pmod{3}=1, 2 \Leftrightarrow 3 \nmid 2^ik \Leftrightarrow 3 \nmid k$. Therefore if $3 \mid k$, then no $i$ satisfies the condition, so we have an even number ($0$) of elements. If $3 \nmid k$, then all $i \in \{0, 1\}$ satisfy the condition, so we have an even number ($2$) of elements.

Consider $n \geq 3$. Observe that $\lceil \frac{2^n-1}{4} \rceil =2^{n-2}>\frac{2^n-1}{4}, \lfloor \frac{3(2^n-1)}{4} \rfloor =3(2^{n-2})-1<\frac{3(2^n-1)}{4}$. Therefore $$\frac{2^n-1}{4}<2^ik \pmod{2^n-1}<\frac{3(2^n-1)}{4} \Leftrightarrow 2^{n-2} \leq 2^ik \pmod{2^n-1} \leq 3(2^{n-2})-1$$

If $k \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n-1}$, then $2^ik \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n-1}$, and $0 \not \in [2^{n-2}, 3(2^{n-2})-1]$, so we have an even number ($0$) of elements.

Consider $k \not \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n-1}$. Let $$A=\{2^{n-2}, 2^{n-2}+1, \ldots, 2^{n-1}-1\}, B=\{2^{n-1}, 2^{n-1}+1, \ldots, 3(2^{n-2})-1\}$$

We are thus interested in the number of $i \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}$ such that $2^ik \pmod{2^n-1} \in A \cup B$.

We first prove a lemma:

**Lemma 1:** If $1 \leq x \leq 2^{n-1}-1$, then $2^ax \in A$ for some $a \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}$, and $2^lx \not \in A \cup B$ for $0 \leq l<a$. If $2^{n-1} \leq x \leq 2^n-2$, then $(2^n-1)-2^b[2^n-1-x]=2^bx \pmod{2^n-1} \in B$ for some $b \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}$, and $(2^n-1)-2^l[2^n-1-x] \not \in A \cup B$ for $0 \leq l<b$.

**Proof:** Suppose that $1 \leq x \leq 2^{n-1}-1$. If $x \in A$, we are done. Otherwise we have $1 \leq x \pmod{2^n-1} \leq 2^{n-2}-1$. Consider the sequence $x, 2x, 4x, \ldots , 2^{n-1}x$. We have $x<2^{n-2}$ and $2^{n-1}x>2^{n-1}-1$. Consider the smallest $a \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}$ s.t. $2^ax \geq 2^{n-2}$. Clearly $a>0$. Since $a$ is minimal, $2^{a-1}x<2^{n-2}$, so $2^{n-2} \leq 2^ax<2^{n-1}$, so $2^ax \in A$. Now for $0 \leq l<a$ we have $1 \leq x \leq 2^lx \leq 2^{a-1}x<2^{n-2}$ so $2^lx \not \in A \cup B$.

Suppose that $2^{n-1} \leq x \leq 2^n-2$. If $x \in B$, then $(2^n-1)-[2^n-1-x]=x \in B$, so we are done. Otherwise we have $3(2^{n-2}) \leq x \leq 2^n-2$. Then $1 \leq 2^n-1-x \leq 2^{n-2}-1$, so by above $2^b(2^n-1-x) \in A$ for some $b \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}$ and $2^l(2^n-1-x) \not \in A \cup B$ for $0 \leq l<b$, so $2^n-1-2^b(2^n-1-x)=2^bx \pmod{2^n-1} \in B$ and $2^n-1-2^l(2^n-1-x) \not \in A \cup B$ for $0 \leq l<b$.

**Continuing**, we note that by Lemma $1$, since $k \not \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n-1}$, $2^l[k \pmod{2^n-1}] \in A \cup B$ for some $l \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$. Now \begin{align} & \{2^ik \pmod{2^n-1}, i \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}\} \\ & =\{2^i(2^l[k \pmod{2^n-1}]) \pmod{2^n-1}, i \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}\} \end{align} (where here we are considering multisets), so the number of $i$ satisfying the condition is the same for $k$ and $2^l[k \pmod{2^n-1}]$. This implies that it suffices to consider $k \in A \cup B$.

Now consider a directed graph $G$ with $2^{n-1}$ vertices representing the $2^{n-1}$ numbers in $A \cup B$. Denote the vertex representing a number $k \in A \cup B$ as $v_k$. There is an directed edge from $v_{k_1}$ to $v_{k_2}$ if and only if $2^lk_1 \pmod{2^n-1}=k_2$ for some $l \in \{1, 2, \ldots , n-1\}$ and $2^jk_1 \pmod{2^n-1}\not \in A \cup B$ for $0<j<l$. In other words, $k_2$ is the first term in the sequence $2^1k_1 \pmod{2^n-1}, 2^2k_1 \pmod{2^n-1}, \ldots$ which is in $A \cup B$. (If $2^lk_1 \not \in A \cup B$ for any $l \in \{1, 2, \ldots , n-1\}$, then there is no directed edge leaving $v_{k_1}$) *Note: We allow $G$ to be a multigraph, so we can have a directed edge from $v_{k_1}$ to $v_{k_2}$ and a directed edge from $v_{k_2}$ to $v_{k_1}$.*

We can easily see that given fixed $k_1$, there is at most 1 value of $k_2$, by definition. Similarly given fixed $k_2$, there is at most 1 value of $k_1$. (Since $k_1$ is the first term in the sequence $2^{-1}k_1 \pmod{2^n-1}, 2^{-2}k_2 \pmod{2^n-1}, \ldots$ which is in $A \cup B$) As such, each vertex has indegree $\leq 1$ and outdegree $\leq 1$. Since $2^nk \equiv k \pmod{2^n-1}$, clearly each vertex either belongs to a cycle or is isolated.

Now consider some $k \in A \cup B$. Suppose that $d$ is the smallest positive integer s.t $2^dk \equiv k \pmod{2^n-1}$. Then $d=ord_{\frac{2^n-1}{\gcd(k, 2^n-1)}}(2)$ and $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod{\frac{2^n-1}{\gcd(k, 2^n-1)}}$, so $d \mid n$. Thus among  $k \pmod{2^n-1}, 2k \pmod{2^n-1}, \ldots , 2^{n-1}k \pmod{2^n-1}$, each of the numbers $k \pmod{2^n-1}, 2k \pmod{2^n-1}, \ldots , 2^{d-1}k \pmod{2^n-1}$ appears exactly $\frac{n}{d}$ times. Let $c$ be the length of the cycle containing $v_k$. (If $v_k$ is isolated then let $c=1$.) Then there are $c$ elements $i \in \{0, 1, \ldots , d-1\}$ s.t. $2^ik \pmod{2^n-1} \in A \cup B$, so there are $c(\frac{n}{d})$ elements $i \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}$ s.t. $2^ik \pmod{2^n-1} \in A \cup B$. Therefore we want to show that $c(\frac{n}{d})$ is always even. To do this, it suffices to show that $c$ is always even, or equivalently, that $G$ has no odd cycles. It thus suffices to show that $G$ is bipartite.

Consider $A_1=\{2^{n-2}, 2^{n-2}+1, \ldots , 3(2^{n-3})-1\}, A_2=\{3(2^{n-3}), 3(2^{n-3})+1, \ldots , 2^{n-1}-1\}$ so $A=A_1 \cup A_2$.

For each $k \in A_1$, we have $2k \in B$, so there is a directed edge from each vertex $v_k, k \in A_1$ to $v_{2k}, 2k \in B$. Clearly if $k, k' \in A_1, k \not =k'$, then $2k \not =2k'$.

Consider $k \in A_2$. Then $3(2^{n-2})-1<2k\leq 2^n-2$, $2k \not \in B$. By Lemma $1$, we have $(2^n-1)-2^b[2^n-1-2k]=2^{b+1}k \pmod{2^n-1} \in B$ for some $b \in \{0, 1, \ldots , n-1\}$, where $b$ is unique. We have $(2^n-1)-2^l[2^n-1-2k] \not \in A \cup B$ for $0 \leq l<b$. Also $b\not =n-1$, otherwise $k=2^nk \pmod{2^n-1} \in B$, a contradiction. Thus $b+1 \in\{1, 2, \ldots , n-1\}$. Therefore there is a directed edge from each vertex $v_k, k \in A_2$ to $v_z, z=(2^n-1)-2^b[2^n-1-2k] \in B$. Note that $z=(2^n-1)-2^b[2^n-1-2k]$ is odd. Also the odd part of $2^n-1-z$ is $2^n-1-2k$, which is different for different $k$. Therefore each $k$ gives a distinct value for $z=(2^n-1)-2^b[2^n-1-2k]$.

As such, we have shown that there is a directed edge from each vertex in $A_G$ to a unique vertex in $B_G$, where $A_G=\{v_k, k \in A \}, B_G=\{v_k, k \in B \}$. (so no $2$ of these directed edges share a vertex) Consider any other directed edge in $G$, if any. It cannot start from any vertex in $A_G$ since each vertex has outdegree $\leq 1$, and we already have a directed edge leaving each vertex in $A_G$. Similarly, it cannot end at any vertex in $B_G$, since each vertex has indegree $\leq 1$, and we already have a directed edge ending at each vertex in $B_G$.

Therefore there are no directed edges among vertices in $A_G$, and no directed edges among vertices in $B_G$, so $G$ is bipartite, and we are done.

Comment: If there is any mistake in the argument, please let me know so that it can be fixed.